# User memory limit exceeded in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am trying to perform non-parametric test of a range of time: Jan-2017 to Jul-2017.

This is the code that has an error(User memory limit exceeded):

```
//Product
var MCD19A2_AOD_055 = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MCD19A2_GRANULES');

// Collect bands and scale
var MCD19A2_AOD_055 = MCD19A2.select('Optical_Depth_055');

// Multiply by scale factor & Conversion of Units
var MCD19A2 = MCD19A2_AOD_055.map(function(img) {
  return img.multiply(0.001).copyProperties(img,['system:time_start','system:time_end']); 
});



//Select period
var MCD19A2 = MCD19A2.filterDate('2017-01-01', '2017-07-31');

//Clip to Specified Region
var clipped_MCD19A2 = MCD19A2.mean().clip(Islamabad);

//Time Series Charts
var AOD = ui.Chart.image.series(MCD19A2, IESE, ee.Reducer.mean(), 1000, 'system:time_start').setOptions({
          title: 'Combined MODIS AOD Daily 1km',
          vAxis: {title: 'AOD'},
});
print(AOD);

var palette = ['black', 'blue', 'purple', 'cyan', 'green', 'yellow', 'red'];

//Set Center of Map & Add Clipped Image Layer
Map.centerObject(Islamabad, 10); //shapefile, zoom
Map.addLayer (clipped_MCD19A2, {min: -0.5, max: 1.0, palette: palette}, 'Optical Depth 055');

//Join the time series to itself
var afterFilter = ee.Filter.lessThan({
  leftField: 'system:time_start',
  rightField: 'system:time_start'
});

var joined = ee.ImageCollection(ee.Join.saveAll('after').apply({
  primary: MCD19A2,
  secondary: MCD19A2,
  condition: afterFilter
}));

var sign = function(i, j) { // i and j are images
  return ee.Image(j).neq(i) // Zero case
      .multiply(ee.Image(j).subtract(i).clamp(-1, 1)).int();
};

//Mann-Kendall trend test
var kendall = ee.ImageCollection(joined.map(function(current) {
  var afterCollection = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(current.get('after'));
  return afterCollection.map(function(image) {
    // The unmask is to prevent accumulation of masked pixels that
    // result from the undefined case of when either current or image
    // is masked.  It won't affect the sum, since it's unmasked to zero.
    return ee.Image(sign(current, image)).unmask(0);
  });
  // Set parallelScale to avoid User memory limit exceeded.
}).flatten()).reduce('sum', 2);

var palette = ['red', 'white', 'green'];
// Stretch this as necessary.
Map.addLayer(kendall, {palette: palette}, 'kendall');

var slope = function(i, j) { // i and j are images
  return ee.Image(j).subtract(i)
      .divide(ee.Image(j).date().difference(ee.Image(i).date(), 'days'))
      .rename('slope')
      .float();
};

var slopes = ee.ImageCollection(joined.map(function(current) {
  var afterCollection = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(current.get('after'));
  return afterCollection.map(function(image) {
      return ee.Image(slope(current, image));
  });
}).flatten());

var sensSlope = slopes.reduce(ee.Reducer.median(), 2); // Set parallelScale.
Map.addLayer(sensSlope, {palette: palette}, 'sensSlope');

var epochDate = ee.Date('2017-05-01');
var sensIntercept = MCD19A2.map(function(image) {
  var epochDays = image.date().difference(epochDate, 'days').float();
  return image.subtract(sensSlope.multiply(epochDays)).float();
}).reduce(ee.Reducer.median(), 2);
Map.addLayer(sensIntercept, {}, 'sensIntercept');

// Values that are in a group (ties).  Set all else to zero.
var groups = MCD19A2.map(function(i) {
  var matches = MCD19A2.map(function(j) {
    return i.eq(j); // i and j are images.
  }).sum();
  return i.multiply(matches.gt(1));
});

// Compute tie group sizes in a sequence.  The first group is discarded.
var group = function(array) {
  var length = array.arrayLength(0);
  // Array of indices.  These are 1-indexed.
  var indices = ee.Image([1])
      .arrayRepeat(0, length)
      .arrayAccum(0, ee.Reducer.sum())
      .toArray(1);
  var sorted = array.arraySort();
  var left = sorted.arraySlice(0, 1);
  var right = sorted.arraySlice(0, 0, -1);
  // Indices of the end of runs.
  var mask = left.neq(right)
  // Always keep the last index, the end of the sequence.
      .arrayCat(ee.Image(ee.Array([[1]])), 0);
  var runIndices = indices.arrayMask(mask);
  // Subtract the indices to get run lengths.
  var groupSizes = runIndices.arraySlice(0, 1)
      .subtract(runIndices.arraySlice(0, 0, -1));
  return groupSizes;
};

// See equation 2.6 in Sen (1968).
var factors = function(image) {
  return image.expression('b() * (b() - 1) * (b() * 2 + 5)');
};

var groupSizes = group(groups.toArray());
var groupFactors = factors(groupSizes);
var groupFactorSum = groupFactors.arrayReduce('sum', [0])
      .arrayGet([0, 0]);

var count = joined.count();

var kendallVariance = factors(count)
    .subtract(groupFactorSum)
    .divide(18)
    .float();
Map.addLayer(kendallVariance, {}, 'kendallVariance');

// get fire data 2017
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('FIRMS').filter(ee.Filter.date('2017-05-01', '2017-07-31'));
var fire = dataset.select('T21').max();
Map.addLayer(fire.clip(Islamabad), {min:300,max:400,palette:['red', 'orange', 'yellow']}, 'Fires - April 2019');
```

Comment: Read through the documentation and see if anything applies to your code: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/debugging#user-memory-limit-exceeded

Comment: @JonasV I tried but it couldn't work for this case.